# Doctrine - parent child query result relation

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, entity, symfony-3.4

I am trying to pull tree of data - with single entity. Parent with it's child relations.

However, my database is not empty but result is returning empty array result.

Any suggestions?

This is my entity: (also with getters and setters)

```
class MyClass  
{

public function __construct()
{
    $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyClass", inversedBy="children")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @Groups({"data"})
 */
private $parentAccount;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MyClass", mappedBy="parentAccount")
 */
private $children;
```

And my query builder:

```
$query = $this->getMyClassRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('q')
        ->leftJoin('q.parentAccount', 'q')
        ->where('q.children = :children')
        ->getQuery();

    return $query;
```

Comment: Are you binding the ```:children``` parameter in the query?

Comment: That is a mistake I am returnig all results with it's children. I am not binding any parameters. @Kyrre

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set the children by a value :

```
   $query = $this->getMyClassRepository()
            ->createQueryBuilder('q')
            ->leftJoin('q.parentAccount', 'q')
            ->where('q.children = :children')
            ->setParameter('children', $children)

            ->getQuery();

        return $query;
```

Comment: Thanks for replay. I found the items with         $children = $result[0]->getParentAccount()->getChildren();
 but still empty.. :/  @MohammedYassineCHABLI